# Not able to understand array of classes

Tags: java

Here is a brief code snippet:

```
someMethod ClassA getClassA() {
  List<ClassA.ClassB> classAType = Lists.newArrayList();
  //Now classAType is loaded with stuff here
  return ClassA.load(classAType.toArray(new ClassA.ClassB[classAType.size()]));
}

public abstract class ClassA {
  //Constructor
  public static abstract class ClassB {
    //some method
  }
}
```

The part which I don't understand is the `return` statement.I wanted to know what does `ClassA.ClassB[classAType.size()]` imply

Comment: It's returning whatever the method `ClassA.load` returns.

Comment: `load` returns the type `ClassA`

Comment: ... which is the return type of the method `getClassA()` which is  `ClassA`

Comment: @noMAD You have answered your own question.

Comment: I think I might have presented my question in a wrong way. I wanted to know what does `ClassA.ClassB[classAType.size()]` imply. Array of classes of type `ClassB`?

Comment: I hope those aren't the variable names you're using in a real program, they'll make it hard to understand for a lot of people :p

Comment: To me, it looks quite nonsensical to instantialize an abstract class...

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: no :) these are not variable names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getClassA()` method first creates a list with `ClassA.ClassB` objects returned by `Lists.newArrayList()`. Then, it returns `ClassA` by calling a static method `ClassA.load()` passing one parameter: an empty array of type `ClassA.ClassB` with the same size as the `classAType`.

This piece of code:

```
classAType.toArray(new ClassA.ClassB[classAType.size()])
```

may look a bit complicated but it just creates an array containing all elements from the `classAType` list.

Answer (score 0):

```
new ClassA.ClassB[classAType.size()]
```

returns an array of `ClassA.ClassB` objects of size `classAType.size()`

since `ClassAType` is a `List` created with `Lists.newArrayList()` (`Lists.newArrayList()` is not defined here so the next part is an assumption), `classAType.size()` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

It's setting the size of the array. However it's going to be 0 because you never put anything in the arraylist. The code doesn't make a whole lot of sense...

Comment: I have a comment there which says that I load the arrayList. I didn't show it here cause its not pertaining to my question.